# What does it mean to have a golden complete?

Tags: mcpixel

After playing McPixel for a while, I completed a level and got a golden background.  Normally they are white, but this time it's Gold!  Does this mean something special?

I know it doesn't mean that I beat it on the first try, because I certainly did not.  Also, I didn't get a gold one for the ones I did beat on the first try.  It also does not mean I hit a bonus round that time.

[image: Gold Icon]

To help explain the picture:

- White backgrounds mean the level was completed
- Brown means failed and have to re-do
- Black (not shown) means yet to be attempted
- Gold means ???

Comment: I'm unclear why the title is asking about sex work.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Is that better?

Comment: Much less confusing!

Comment: I think the colors are supposed to be Black -> Bronze -> Silver -> Gold.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A golden complete means you have seen every ending for that level.

This **DOES** include

- Using different items with all the sources that end the scene
- Using all the sources that end the scene without holding items

This **DOES NOT** include

- Letting the timer run out
- Interacting with items that are not picked up, do not end the scene, and are generally useless (i.e. kicking something and the timer keeps running and the scene does not change in any way)

Getting gold completes, like getting white completes, will begin a stack of 3 squares.  If you get all 3, you get a bonus round (Same as the White Complete bonus rounds).  You can lose these squares if you repeat an ending for a scene.  However, as long as you are getting new endings, you do not need to get the golden completes in immediate succession as you do with the white completes.

Comment: This sounds about right. Especially for the special round of Chapter 4: to get gold, you just need to click every possible combo. There was some guy on Steam inquiring about this, and the internet turned out to be extremely vague on this point: https://steamcommunity.com/app/220860/discussions/0/522730700582907532/

Answer (score 3):

Actually, a golden means you have found the "gag" in that level (it does not mean you have to win on the level). There is one gag hidden in each level, and after getting three you will get a bonus round.

Collecting gold squares will unlock extras in the Extras menu, that is their purpose. A good way to get a lot of gold squares is by playing on endless mode.

Comment: This does not match up with my testing.  To get the golden square, I had to end the scene in every way possible.  I was doing this on Steam, so perhaps there are platform differences.

Comment: @Batophobia Actually, I read my information directly from the help section in the game, and they definitely call them gags.

Comment: Each unsuccessful ending (aside from letting the timer run out) is referred to as a "gag", and you have to find all of them in a scene to get gold.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, just to clarify.

You need to get every possible ending animation on a level to get the gold square, the way I did this was simply click every object with every possible combination of object in my hand. No it's not the fastest way, but it's probably the best to make sure you don't miss any.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer, but could you perhaps elaborate a bit more than this?

Comment: Okay so in every scene there are various possible endings, obtained by clicking all the things in every way they can be clicked. So click an object and if it gives you a specific ending, try clicking holding things that you are able to hold.

Comment: For example in the carnival with the cake things, click each cake holding the water pistol, and each one not holding it. I managed to get gold by simply clicking everything in every possible combination.

Comment: You might want to insert those amendments into the answer rather than leave them as comments.

Comment: This is correct, but not every object you can interact with is required for this.